# HTML5: video source not working in the Firefox 21.0, Ubuntu

Tags: html, firefox, ubuntu, html5-video

I am new to the "Html5". When i am trying to implement a simple video tag I got an error "No video with supported format and MIME type found". My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <!source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4 codecs='avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2'" />
    <!source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

please help me
i am using firefox version 21.0 as browser and  Ubuntu Ultimate Edition 3.0 as OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not support the mp4 video format in HTML5.
<s>http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp</s>

**Edit:** it looks like Firefox supports mp4 in some cases (thanks @winterblood). So if you use Firefox 21, [mp4 should work with Windows 7+, Android and Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

Comment: Please, don't link people to w3schools. It is a terribly basic website that often features incorrect or misleading information. Instead link people to a reputable (and much more often correct) source like the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) docs. For HTML5 video format compatibility, specifically see the [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) page.

Comment: @Romain  I am  using Ubuntu Ultimate Edition 3.0.

Comment: @omrehman, so that must be the reason you cannot play your mp4 video. Try converting it to another format like ogg, and add both sources in your `<video>` tag.